# Android Studio, run main from Java Library, deprecation, run from command line

Tags: java, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Starting with Android Studio 3.6.1 I get a warning when running a main method in a Java Library module (I just want to quickly do something with the library code)

```
> Task :lib:compileJava
> Task :lib:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :lib:classes
> Task :lib:Something.main()
Hello World
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.4/userguide 
/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

It still works, but fills the output window and is something to be changed, I assume? 
I am also unable to run the main method from the command line with gradle (thus I cannot further investigate with warning-mode all). I can do `./gradlew :lib:compileJava` and other targets, I can do in the lib directory `../gradlew compileJava` or just `../gradlew build`, but I cannot run the target with `./gradlew :lib:Something.main()` as it is suggested in the Android Studio output window.

What do I need to do, to get rid of the warning? What do I need to type to run a main-Method from a Java Library on the command line with gradle? Any help appreciated.